# Start slick slider at start of bootstrap container and scroll in full width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slick.js

It's bit hard do describe what I want. But let's try... ;-)

I'm using the slick slider to show 5 of 10 items.
The slider should use the whole width of the page but the first item shouldn't start at the very left of the page but at the start of the container.

**This is my actual code / working example:** https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/MQmeNN

```
<div class="bg-dark text-white py-5">
    <div class="container mb-5">
        <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h1>Headline</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-end">
                <div class="slider-arrows"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slider-services text-dark">
        <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">1</div>
        <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">2</div>
        <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">3</div>
        <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">4</div>
        <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">5</div>
        <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">6</div>
        <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">7</div>
        <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">8</div>
        <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">9</div>
        <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the slider starts at the left of the page.
Is there any way with Bootstrap 4 to start the slider inside the container width (align with the headline) and scroll to the left of the page?

Comment: is this what you mean? https://snag.gy/3iRDyP.jpg

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i meant

Comment: Kewl, I'm starting to code this with slick too, if I come up with a a solution I'll post here.

Comment: great! thank you very much

Comment: Solution posted, hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a much better solution than before (see edits) all you need to do is to set the `slick-list` overflow to visible and ensure that your parent container has it hidden.

```
.container-fluid{overflow:hidden;}
.slick-list{overflow:visible;}
```

See https://codepen.io/pnmcosta/pen/GYpxgr for example.

**Update 1**

Added some updates to the example, supports faded edges, arrows and dots.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the slider into your container div.

```css
$('.slider-services').slick({
    dots: false,
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"> <- </button>',
    nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"> -> </button>',
    appendArrows:$('.slider-arrows'),
    slidesToShow: 5,

   });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.0/slick.min.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.0/slick-theme.min.css" />


<div class="bg-dark text-white py-5">
  <div class="container mb-5">
   <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <h1>Headline</h1>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-end">
     <div class="slider-arrows"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
      <div class="slider-services text-dark">
     <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">1</div>
     <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">2</div>
     <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">3</div>
     <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">4</div>
     <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">5</div>
     <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">6</div>
     <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">7</div>
     <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">8</div>
     <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">9</div>
     <div class="p-5 mx-3 bg-light">10</div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.0/slick.js"></script>
```

Comment: When I do this, the slider wouldn't use the whole width of the page when I scroll

Comment: Can you please explain this further?

Comment: At the beginning I want the first slider item aligned with the container. To the right, the slider should grow outside the container to the right of the page. After I slide, the container should grow to the left. Outside the container.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your desired behavior. Especially not why you want your slider to overgrow the container. As it's name suggests, the container should always be the wrapping component.

Comment: It’s for design reasons only. I will try to find an example

Comment: I‘m on mobile right now. But this should look like what I want: https://saucal.com/process/consult/